# Big Query Regex Extraction

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I am trying to extract a item_subtype field from an URL.

This regex works fine in the to get the first item `item_type`

`SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('info?item_type=icecream&item_subtype=chocolate/cookies%20cream,vanilla&page=1', r'item_type=(\w+)')`

but what is the correct regex to get everything starting from 'chocolate' all the way to before the '&page1'

I have tried this, but can't seem to get it to work to go further

`SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('info?item_type=icecream&item_subtype=chocolate/cookies%20cream,vanilla&page=1', r'item_subtype=(\w+[^Z])')`

basically, I want to extract 'chocolate/cookies%20cream,vanilla'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `\w+` only matches one or more letters, digits or underscores. Your expected values may contain other characters, too.

You may use

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('info?item_type=icecream&item_subtype=chocolate/cookies%20cream,vanilla&page=1', r'item_subtype=([^&]+)')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IRqzNm/1).

**Notes**:

- `item_subtype=` - this string is matched as a literal char sequence
- `([^&]+)` - a Capturing group 1 that matches and captures one or more chars other than `&` into a separate memory buffer that is returned by `REGEXP_EXTRACT` function.